# RuntimeError: inconsistent tensor sizes at /pytorch/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:2864

Tags: python, pytorch

Im trying to build a dataloader, This is what it looks like

```
`class WhaleData(Dataset):
def __init__(self, data_file, root_dir , transform = None):
    self.csv_file = pd.read_csv(data_file)
    self.root_dir = root_dir
    self.transform = transforms.Resize(224)

def __len__(self):
    return len(os.listdir(self.root_dir))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    image = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.csv_file['Image'][index])
    image = Image.open(image)
    image = self.transform(image)
    image = np.array(image)
    label  = self.csv_file['Image'][index]
    sample = {'image': image, 'label':label}
    return sample

trainset  = WhaleData(data_file = '/mnt/55-91e8-b2383e89165f/Ryan/1234/train.csv', 
     root_dir = '/mnt/4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/Ryan/1234/train')
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset , batch_size = 4, shuffle =True,num_workers= 2)
for i, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
      (i, batch)
```

When i try running this block of code, i get this error,I do get the nature of the error that all my images may not be of the same shape,and my images are not all of the same shape ,But if im not wrong the error should only arise when i feed them to the network because the images are all of different shapes,But why is it throwing an errror here?
Any suggestions on where i might have gone wrong will be extremly helpful,
I would be happy to provide any extra information if needed,

Thanks

```
RuntimeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 42, in _worker_loop
samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 116, in default_collate
    return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in batch[0]}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 116, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in batch[0]}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 105, in default_collate
return torch.stack([torch.from_numpy(b) for b in batch], 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/functional.py", line 64, in stack
    return torch.cat(inputs, dim)
RuntimeError: inconsistent tensor sizes at /pytorch/torch/lib/TH/generic    /THTensorMath.c:2864
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears when PyTorch tries to stack together the images into a single batch tensor (cf. `torch.stack([torch.from_numpy(b) for b in batch], 0)` from your trace). As you mentioned, since the images have different shape, the stacking fails (i.e. a tensor `(B, H, W)` can only be created by stacking `B` tensors if all these tensors have for shape `(H, W)`).

---

Note: I'm not fully sure, but setting `batch_size=1` for `torch.utils.data.DataLoader(...)` may remove this particular error, as it probably won't need calling `torch.stack()` anymore).

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, Any suggestions on how i may resize all my images to fixed dimensions,say(224,224),Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to set `self.transform = transforms.Resize((224, 224))` for your `WhaleData` instead? (giving only an `int` as parameter for `Resize()` sets the largest side of the image to that size ; giving a `tuple` sets both the height and width accordingly c.f. [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize))

Comment: (... the aspect ratio wouldn't be preserved though)